# Connecting to Docker Host on Windows running WSL2. Does not appear to be listening on port 2376

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I'm running Docker Desktop on Windows, in WSL2 mode. I'm also running Jenkins on the Windows machine, but not within docker. I'm trying to set up Docker in Jenkins, but it cannot connect to the local Docker Host. "Connection Refused".

If I look at services, Docker Desktop Service is running, but when I run netstat, I don't see anything listening on port 2376.

I have a feeling that it has to do with WSL2, but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Network-accessible Docker is hard to configure securely, and if you get it wrong, it's all but trivial to use it to remotely compromise the host.  I wouldn't normally expect to see anything listening on port 2375 or 2376.  Do you expect something different?  Why?  How does your code use these ports, and can you configure it to use the default local socket connection instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze - This is so that a Jenkins server can spin up containers. Why would setting up network assessable docker be hard?

Comment: Because you can `docker -H http://jenkins.example.com:2375 run --rm -it -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/shadow` and trivially remotely take over the system.